# Transform object array to new array structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, lodash

Apologies but I am learning array manipulation, tried a few things as I have done similar before but just cant figure this out. I am building a react application and have got my data back from the UI but need to reformat for the API. My payload looks like this...

```
0: {from: "U20", Id: "1922", to: "U21"}
1: {from: "U20", Id: "9338", to: "U21"}
2: {from: "U20", Id: "1927", to: "U21"}
3: {from: "U20", Id: "1730", to: "U21"}
```

I need to create a group for all the `ids` and post back the `from` and `to` fields.

```
{
    "from": "U20",
    "Ids": ["1922","9338","1927","1730"],
    "to:": "U21"
}
```

I have lodash as a helper library.

Comment: could you have more than one `from` and `to` values?

Comment: No, sorry forgot to say, those values will be the same for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To group based on 2 keys, you could do something like this using `reduce`. Create an accumulator object with a new key which is combination of `from` and `to`

```js
const input = [
    { from: "U20", Id: "1922", to: "U21" },
    { from: "U20", Id: "9338", to: "U21" },
    { from: "U20", Id: "1927", to: "U21" },
    { from: "U20", Id: "1730", to: "U21" }
];

const merged = input.reduce((acc, { from, to, Id }) => {
    const key = `${from}-${to}`;
    acc[key] = acc[key] || { from, to, Ids:[] };
    acc[key]["Ids"].push(Id);
    return acc;
}, {})

const output = Object.values(merged);
console.log(output);
```

In your case, if you just want the first object, then `output[0]`

Answer (score 1):

If there's a possibility of there being different values in the `from` and `to` fields, then your API would need to change to accept an array of values instead of one string. However, working on the assumption that the `from` and `to` values will always be the same across each item in the array...

```
const payload = [
  {from: "U20", Id: "9338", to: "U21"},
  {from: "U20", Id: "1927", to: "U21"},
  {from: "U20", Id: "1730", to: "U21"},
];

const newValue = {
  from: payload[0].from,
  to: payload[0].to,
  Ids: payload.map(item => item.Id)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = [
  {from: "U20", Id: "1922", to: "U21"},
  {from: "U20", Id: "9338", to: "U21"},
  {from: "U20", Id: "1927", to: "U21"},
  {from: "U20", Id: "1730", to: "U21"},
  {from: "U21", Id: "1745", to: "U22"},
  {from: "U21", Id: "1755", to: "U22"},
]

const f = array => {
  const result = []
  // key-value storage
  const variations = {}
  array.forEach(item => {
    // set storage key
    const key = `${item.from}-${item.to}`;
    // check if key exists
    // if exists use it, if not - create empty array
    variations[key] = variations[key] || []
    // push item ids to storage
    variations[key].push(item.Id)
  })
  Object.keys(variations).map(variation => {
    // deconstruct storage key back to "from" and "to" values
    const [from, to] = variation.split('-');
    const obj = {};
    // write "from" and "to" values
    obj.from = from;
    obj.to = to;
    // add stored values
    obj.ids = variations[variation]
    // save
    result.push(obj)
  })
  console.log(result)
}

f(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the following you can keep a record of every list of `Ids` for every `from` -> `to` key pair.

```js
const entries = [
 { from: 'U20', to: 'U21', Id: '1922' },
 { from: 'U20', to: 'U21', Id: '9338' },
 { from: 'U20', to: 'U21', Id: '1927' },
 { from: 'U20', to: 'U21', Id: '1730' },
]

const output = entries.reduce((map, {from, to, Id}) =>
{
 if (!map[from])
 {
  map[from] = {}
 }
 
 if (!map[from][to])
 {
  map[from][to] = {from, to, Ids: []}
 }
 
 map[from][to].Ids.push(Id)
 
 return map
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array reduce and in the accumulator pass an empty object. Use `hasOwnProperty` to check if the object has the property `from` and if its value matches, then in the `id` array push the value

```js
let data = [{
    from: "U20",
    Id: "1922",
    to: "U21"
  },
  {
    from: "U20",
    Id: "9338",
    to: "U21"
  },
  {
    from: "U20",
    Id: "1927",
    to: "U21"
  },
  {
    from: "U20",
    Id: "1730",
    to: "U21"
  }
]


let newData = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  if (acc.hasOwnProperty('from') && acc.from === curr.from) {
    acc.id.push(curr.Id)
  } else {
    acc = {
      from: curr.from,
      id: [curr.Id],
      to: curr.to
    }

  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var idArray = [];
var newObj = {};
 var objArray = [{
    "from": "U20",
    "Id": "1922",
    "to": "U21"
},
{
    "from": "U20",
    "Id": "9338",
    "to": "U21"
},
{
    "from": "U20",
    "Id": "1927",
    "to": "U21"
},
{
    "from": "U20",
    "Id": "1730",
    "to": "U21"
}
]

      for(var i=0; i<objArray.length; i++) {
    for(var key in objArray[i]) {
      if(key == 'Id') idArray.push(objArray[i][key])
    }
  }
  newObj.from = objArray[0].from;
  newObj.to = objArray[0].to;
  newObj.Id = idArray;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach by taking a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and a joined key for the grouping with two values.

```js
var data = [{ from: "U20", Id: "1922", to: "U21" }, { from: "U20", Id: "9338", to: "U21" }, { from: "U20", Id: "1927", to: "U21" }, { from: "U20", Id: "1730", to: "U21" }, { from: "U20", Id: "1730", to: "U22" }, { from: "U21", Id: "1730", to: "U22" }],
    result = Array.from(data
        .reduce(
             (m, { from, to, Id }) =>
                 (k => m.set(k, { from, to, Ids: [...(m.has(k) ? m.get(k).Ids : []), Id] }))
                 ([from, to].join('|')),
             new Map
        )
        .values()
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

And one more decision:

```
const compare = (o1, o2) => o1.from === o2.from && o1.to === o2.to
return entries
    .reduce((arr,entry) => !arr.find(a=>compare(a,entry)) ? arr.concat(entry) : arr, [])
    .map( ({from,to})=> ({
        from,
        to,
        ids: entries.filter(i=>compare(i,{from,to})).map(({id})=>id)
        }))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that uses [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) to group all objects in the array by the combination of the `from` and `to` props. Then it maps all groups back to array, by merge all objects in each group. If the merged props is `Id`, it concats the values to an array.

```js
const { flow, groupBy, props, join, map, mergeAllWith, cond, nthArg, eq, concat } = _;

const fn = flow(
  groupBy(flow(                // group by joining from and to as the key
    props(['from', 'to']),
    join('-')
  )),
  map(mergeAllWith(cond([[     // merge all objects in each group
    flow(nthArg(2), eq('Id')), // if the prop name is Id, concat the values
    concat
  ]])))
);

const input = [
    { from: "U20", Id: "1922", to: "U21" },
    { from: "U20", Id: "9338", to: "U21" },
    { from: "U20", Id: "1927", to: "U21" },
    { from: "U20", Id: "1730", to: "U21" }
];

const result = fn(input);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. You can do this

```
const arr = [
     {from: "U20", Id: "1922", to: "U21"},
     {from: "U20", Id: "9338", to: "U21"},
     {from: "U20", Id: "1927", to: "U21"},
     {from: "U20", Id: "1730", to: "U21"}]

const newObject = {
    from: arr[0].from,
    Ids: arr.map(record => (record.Id)),
    to: arr[0].to
    }
```